# See Pending Changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We use Team Foundation Server (now Azure DevOps) in conjunction with Visual Studio as our version control system.

I am our teams ssrs report developer and, unfortunately, sometimes throughout the course of my day I'll be working on multiple projects and will have a report checked out, however I'm unsure what changes I might have pending (it could be something actually valuable for production, or just something I was testing). Is there a built in way to compare pending changes to the code vs the current saved version?

Comment: Did you try right clicking on the file in the source control explorer and looking at the available options?

Comment: Well I feel real stupid! @DanielMann that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Daniel Mann's excellent comment, the answer is very simple. Right click > Compare!